# SQL - How to find records older than x days and not occurs after x days

Tags: sql

I have a table with logging records (login_time, user_name) and I need to find records which are older than 90 days and didn't occur after this time. 
So it will be a list of users that for eg. has been visiting my page several times but from some reasons they stopped.

I have query only for listing records older than 90 days and I don't know waht to put next.

```
SELECT
    "u_user_name",
    "login_time"
FROM
    table
WHERE
    "login_time" < now()-interval'90'day
```

Thanks in advance
Nullo

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.) Also tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT u_user_name, max(login_time) as most_recent_login_time
FROM table t
GROUP BY u_user_name
HAVING MAX(login_time) < now() - interval '90' day;
```